# Remove duplicate elements from list

Tags: prolog

This is my code

```
removevowels(L1, L2) :-
   removevowels(L1, L2, []).

removevowels([], [], _).
removevowels([X|L1], [X|L2], Aux) :-
   consonant(X), 
   not(member(X, Aux)), 
   removevowels(L1, L2, [X|Aux]).
removevowels([X|L1], L2, Aux) :-
   not(consonant(X)), 
   removevowels(L1, L2, Aux).
```

If i run this:

```
?- removevowels([a,m,m,n], X).
```

It should print

```
X = [m, n]
```

but it's giving false and if i run this

```
?- removevowels([a,m,n], X).
X = [m,n]
```

It's alright when it doesn't have repeated elements.

Auxiliar predicates used:

```
member(X, [X|_]).      
member(X, [_|Tail]) :-   
   member(X, Tail). 

consonant(b)
consonant(c), etcetc ....
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Two answers were offered. Are neither of them acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

The best is to replace `not/1` by the ISO `(\+)/1` first.

For debugging, the first thing you would do is to **minimize the problem**. E.g., the query

```
?- removevowels([m,m],X).
```

is just as bad. But much smaller. So what are your rules for consonants? There is a **single rule**:

```
removevowels([X|L1], [X|L2], Aux) :-
   consonant(X),
   \+member(X, Aux), 
   removevowels(L1, L2, [X|Aux]).
```

So consonants **have** to occur only once, the next occurrence makes this fail already.

Should you still not be sure why the query fails, you might also want to **generalize the query**. In stead of seeing that `removevowels([m,m],X)` fails, you might ask

```
?- removevowels([m,Y],X).
```

which means: Is there *any* `Y` such that there is a solution. However, this method only works, if your program is "relational". In your case the last rule, however prevents this:

```
removevowels([X|L1], L2, Aux) :-
   \+consonant(X), 
   removevowels(L1, L2, Aux).
```

It will never succeed with `X` being an uninstantiated variable. I'd rather use instead:

```
removevowels([X|L1], L2, Aux) :-
   vowel(X), 
   removevowels(L1, L2, Aux).
```

Back to consonants:
What you are missing is either a separate rule for consonants that are already present, or some "defaulty" if-then-else.

Further, this extra checking might not be the most effective way to handle this. Maybe just extract the vowels first, and then `sort/2` them.

Answer (score 0):

in second clause, there are two 2 conditions in join, while the last clause has only one. I would commit the good case with a cut, and let the last clause only act as a trusted skip clause:

```
removevowels([], [], _).
removevowels([X|L1], [X|L2], Aux) :-
   consonant(X), 
   not(member(X, Aux)), 
   !, removevowels(L1, L2, [X|Aux]).
removevowels([_X|L1], L2, Aux) :-
   removevowels(L1, L2, Aux).
```

using if/then/else construct for the last 2 clauses, we avoid the problem noted by false:

```
removevowels([], [], _).
removevowels([X|L1], R, Aux) :-
    (   consonant(X), 
        not(member(X, Aux))
    ->  R=[X|L2],
        removevowels(L1, L2, [X|Aux])
    ;   removevowels(L1, R, Aux)
    ).
```

Comment: This solution lacks *steadfastness*: `removevowels([m],[])` should fail, but here it succeeds.

Comment: The condition `consonant(X), \+member(X,Aux)` now goes too far: In particular `removevowels([X],R)` now produces incorrectly a single answer. Otherwise, the rule for vowels is lacking.